# Why is the hair on my dog's back getting much lighter?

Tags: dogs, health, diseases, veterinarian

I have a doberman and he has a number of issues. My parents refuse to take him to the vet but I think it's something serious. Here are the symptoms.

- Hair on his back has become much lighter.
- He has growths on his nipples that itch.
- He's experiencing slight hair loss on his lower back.
- He gives off a very strong odor.( even a few days after bath)
- He has lost weight.

Please Help.

Comment: It could be sarcoptic mange. If so, he definitely needs to be seen by a vet.

Comment: Unfortunately that is an array of problems that cannot be diagnosed online :( - As a side-note feel free to post pictures of the problematic areas.